# Classnotfound expection whle connecting Driver Manager in JSP and Apache Derby Database/ how to build a database connection for a normal Java App

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, derby, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to get a connection build with JSP and JAVA DERBY Database built in with the NetBeans IDE.

I have checked for the Driver, URL , User and Password everything seems to be perfectly right. The following is the code.

```
      <% Connection con= null; 
       PreparedStatement ps = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
       String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/record";
       String user = "root";
       String password = "root";
       String sql = "select usertype from userdetail";
       try 
       {
         Class.forName(driver);
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
         ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
         rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

     %>
```

I end up getting the following (below) error on the browser

```
 type Exception report

 message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 31

 description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling    this request.

 exception

  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 31

  28:            String sql = "select usertype from userdetail";
  29:            try 
  30:            {
  31:             Class.forName(driver);
  32:              con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
  33:              ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  34:              rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

   Stacktrace:
                                                                                               org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568

   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:                       org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

Please help! 
Thank you

Comment: @ArturMalinowski that's a solution but it's not the best option

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the that 'derbyclient.jar' is on the actual classpath of your application.